# Calling a overridable method in a constructor, even if we specify it's from the super class?

Tags: java, constructor, polymorphism

I understand why calling an overridable method in a contructor is a bad practice and can lead to errors. However, I tried to call a overridable method using the prefix super, to specify that I want to call the method from the super class and not from any other classes.

Consider my example below :

```
public class ObjectMapperExtended extends ObjectMapper {
    // fields and stuff, irrelevant to the problem

    public ObjectMapperExtended () {
        super();
        super.registerModule(new Hibernate4Module());
    }
}
```

Here, I call registerModule which is an overridable method from the super class. However, I clearly indicated that I want to call that method from the super class, and not any other classes, but I still have the warning stating that I shouldn't call a overridable method from a constructor. I got that warning from SonarQube (squid:S1699, to be exact), which I'm running for the static analysis of my code.

Am I misunderstanding something ? Does specifying super in this particular case doesn't do any difference whatsoever ?

PS: the ObjectMapper class used is the one from http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html

Comment: @ProPhil Do you mean warning? Calling a super class method in the subclass constructor is legal.

Comment: @ChetanKinger Indeed, a warning would have been a better word to describe this problem. I shall edit my OP in that regard.

Comment: @ProPhill do you override the method in the subclass?

Comment: @ChetanKinger I do not.

Comment: It is specific to SonarQube Standards I guess.However Netbeans is not showing those warnings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is "safe" in the sense that if the class overrode the method, super's would always be called - perhaps SonarQube is being overly cautious.

However, overridable or not, `this` has escaped the constructor - the instance being initialized could be passed out of `registerModule()` to another process in an incompletely/inconsistently initialized state - so it's bad practice either way. Even if the *current* implementation of the method may *not* pass it out, a future one could (ie upgrading the library could introduce bugs).

To address the problem, you can mark the offending line with `//NOSONAR` to have (all) warnings expressly ignored:

```
public class ObjectMapperExtended extends ObjectMapper {
    public ObjectMapperExtended () {
        super.registerModule(new Hibernate4Module()); //NOSONAR
    }
}
```

or (best practice) use a factory method:

```
public class ObjectMapperExtended extends ObjectMapper {
    private ObjectMapperExtended () {}

    public static ObjectMapperExtended create() {
        ObjectMapperExtended obj = new ObjectMapperExtended();
        obj.registerModule(new Hibernate4Module());
        return obj;
    }
}
```

By the way, calling `super();` is redundant; it may be removed without changing behaviour.